# Корректный перевод нецензурного припева

Tags: перевод, одним-словом

У Лили Аллен есть песня под названием `Fuck you (very much)`. Собственно припев начинается словами `Fuck you, fuck you very very much`. Каковы варианты адаптированного перевода для этой строки?

Насколько я понял это отсылка к сердечной благодарности `thank you,thank you very much` посему мои вариант перевода в том же ключе: `идите нахуй и будьте здоровы`. Будет ли подобное корректным?

UPD: под "адаптированным" я подразумеваю такой перевод, который при переводе по возможности теряет минимум смысла заложенного в изначальном тексте. То есть замена фразеологизмов на аналогичные в русском, сохранение некой игры слов в переводе. Ярким примером может служить поэзия и её переводы на русский (как у Бальмонта, например).

Comment: Что касается, кхм, поэзии, то о корректности перевода есть много противоположных мнений. Советские ВИА и (современные каверщики) вообще старались сохранить фонетическое сходство припева не обращая внимание на смысл.

Comment: The problem with your translation is that it doesn't rhyme.

Comment: Что значит "адаптированный перевод"? Поясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Aksakal yes i know, but i don't can't create any good rhyme until i'll be sure in translation.

Comment: @Sugar, you got the idea right. It certainly is a word play around "thank you, very much". Now you only need to get it rhyme. You may need to deviate from the exact translation though.

Comment: Большое сПОЦиба?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Не думаю, что подойдет как перевод, но если thank you very much - большое спасибо
то перевести fuck you very much сохраняя игру слов и похожесть выражения можно как "большое посасибо". Не особо распространено конечно но пару раз слышал ))

Comment: Ha! You made my day. ))

Comment: In the context of the lyrics of the song, this is a neat solution